Issues with Next.js project using cached URLs
Hi everyone,
I'm currently working on a Next.js project that works perfectly when accessed directly via https://astolabs.com. However, I encounter issues when I try to access the site using a cached URL (like cache:https://astolabs.com) in different browsers.
The main problem is that when the site is accessed from a cached URL, no API calls are made, yet the site remains in a perpetual loading state.
Here are the specific issues I'm facing:
In Chrome :
DOMException: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'https://astolabs.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fastolabs.com&oq=cache%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fastolabs.com&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIGCAEQRRg60gEJMTAxNjJqMGoxqAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8' cannot be created in a document with origin 'https://webcache.googleusercontent.com' and URL 'https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fastolabs.com&oq=cache%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fastolabs.com&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIGCAEQRRg60gEJMTAxNjJqMGoxqAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8'.at Router.changeState (https://astolabs.com/_next/static/chunks/main-3130cf96069fd667.js:1:73312)at https://astolabs.com/_next/static/chunks/main-3130cf96069fd667.js:1:82550at async hydrate (https://astolabs.com/_next/static/chunks/main-3130cf96069fd667.js:1:16595)

In Firefox:
DOMException: The operation is insecure.NextJS 2changeState_initialMatchesMiddlewarePromise

Does anyone have any insights on why these issues might be occurring or suggestions on how to fix them? Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
